# Confusion regarding Functions as Values concept in javascript

Tags: javascript

when we declare a named function let's say in google chrome console and if we call it then the contents of the function are getting executed. how ever if we create a reference for that function and if I am trying to call that function with which it is named, I am getting ReferenceError.

```
function foo() {
 console.log("something");
}
foo(); // will print out "something"
var x = function bar() {
 console.log("something x");
}
x(); //will print "something x"
bar(); //throws ReferenceError, bar is not defined.
```

Comment: the name isn't pushed to the surrounding lexical scope when you assign it as a value to another variable. Only function _statements_ hoist the name like that. The name still works _inside_ the function.

Comment: When you say `var x = function bar()`, the name of your function is x it is not going to be bar. Though, bar will be available within the function (Which can be used to recursively call itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code `function bar(){...}` when assigned to a variable `x` acts as function expression not function declaration .The function `bar` becomes local variable to `x`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_expressions)

> a name can be provided with a function expression and can be used inside the function to refer to itself,

```js
var x = function bar() {
 console.log(bar)
 console.log("something x");
}
x();
```